# Concise initialization syntax for nested variants?

Tags: c++, casting, initialization, variant

I'm working a small C++ JSON library to help sharpen my rusty C++ skills, and I'm having trouble understanding some behavior with initialization lists.

The core of the library is a variant class (named "var") that stores any of the various JSON datatypes (null, boolean, number, string, object, array).

The goal is for `var` to work as closely as possible to a JavaScript variable, so there's lots of operator overloading going on. The primitive datatypes are easy to take care of...

```
var fee = "something";
var fie = 123.45;
var foe = false;
```

The problem is with objects (maps) and arrays (vectors).

To get something close to a JavaScript object and array literal syntax, I'm using initialization lists. It looks like this:

```
// in my headers
typedef var object[][2];
typedef var array[]; 

// in user code
var foo = (array){ 1, "b", true };
var bar = (object){ { "name", "Bob" }, { "age", 42 } };
```

This works out pretty nicely. The problem comes in with nested lists.

```
var foo = (array){ 1, "b", (array){ 3.1, 3.2 } };
```

For some reason my variant class interprets the nested "array" as a boolean, giving:

```
[1, "b", true]
```

Instead of:

```
[1, "b", [3.1, 3.2]]
```

If I explicitly cast the inner list to a var, it works:

```
var foo = (array){ 1, "b", (var)(array){ 3.1, 3.2 } };
```

Why do I have to explicitly cast the inner list to a var after I cast it to an array, and how can I get around this extra cast? As far as I can tell it should be implicitly converting the array to my var class anyway, since it's using the constructor for an array of vars:

```
template <size_t length>
var(const var(&start)[length]) {
  // internal stuff
  init();
  setFromArray(vector<var>(start, start + length));
}
```

It seems that without the explicit cast to var, the initialization list somehow gets cast to something else on its way from being cast from an array to a var. I'm trying to understand why this happens, and how to avoid it.

---

Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/3392320) with the complete source. Let me know if I should add anything relevant to the question.

---

**Update**

Apparently `(foo){1, "two"}` does not actually cast an initialiation list; it's a complete expression called a [compound literal](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals). It seems that it's only available in C, although g++ doesn't complain unless you give it `-pedantic`.

It looks like my options are:

- Find another concise initialization syntax that is officially supported.
- Use compound literals and hope they work in other compilers.
- Drop support for C++ < 11 and use initializer_list.
- Don't offer a concise initialization syntax.

Any help with the first option would be the sort of answer I'm looking for at this point.

Macros are another sort of last-ditch option, and I've written some that do the job, but I'd like to not have to use them.

Comment: It's nigh impossible to understand what's going on without a synopsis of `var`, at least in terms of what constructors and conversion operators (if any) are declared.

Comment: @LucDanton added a link to the source.

Comment: Any other comments on the code in general are also welcome as I don't really have a clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Did you try marking the constructors `explicit`?

Comment: @MichałGórny I didn't (didn't even know about `explicit`). Will try it, thanks.

Comment: @MichałGórny nope, that's pretty much the opposite of what I want. Since it's a variant, I need to be able to assign arbitrary things to it without casting. In this case it would be the constructor for bool that I'd want to make explicit, which would cause stuff like `var foo = true` to fail.

Comment: The question is, why is it getting cast to some intermediate type? A constructor takes an array of vars, one element of that array of vars is an initialization list, cast to an array of vars. Since the constructor is an array of vars, it should now cast that inner array of vars to a var, right? And it did get cast to a var, but apparently not straight from the array, because it used the boolean constructor this time. I'm probably doing a really bad job of explaining this...

Comment: @GGG: sorry, I was just guessing. To be honest, the code you pasted works for me with *clang++* and fails with *g++* (`error: taking address of temporary array`). I'm afraid you are using some undefined behavior…

Comment: (and I meant the code without additional `(var)`). With it, *g++* just dies with internal compiler error :P.

Comment: That's strange, I've been testing this with g++ 4.6.3 (c++0x mode off). What version are you using? Do you think casting the initialization list is undefined behavior, or something else?

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the facilities already provided to you by Boost.

```
typedef boost::optional<boost::make_recursive_variant<
    float, int, bool, //.. etc
    std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::optional<boost::recursive_variant_>>,
    std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
> JSONType;
```

They can easily define recursive variant types.

Comment: Thanks, but as we discussed in  chat, this just replaces my variant with another, it doesn't do anything to solve the problem of having a concise initialization syntax (or improve my understanding of C++, really).